Proving second-order Mean Value Theorem: Do we need to require $f^\prime$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$?
I am currently trying to prove the following statement:

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$ and twice differentiable on $(a,b)$. Show that there exists an $\xi$ in $(a,b)$ such that
$$f(b)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(b-a)+\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)}{2!}(b-a)^2$$

My attempt is as follows:
We apply Rolle's theorem to the function $h(x)=f(x)-f(a)-f^\prime(a)(x-a)-\alpha(x-a)^2$ for an appropriate $\alpha$.
We seek to emulate the proof for the first-order Mean Value Theorem, so we want $h(b)$ to be equal to $h(a)$. Clearly, $h(a)=0$. Therefore, we want $\alpha$ to be such that
$$\tag{1}
0=f(b)-f(a)-f^\prime(a)(b-a)-\alpha(b-a)^2.
$$
In other words,
$$
\alpha=\frac{1}{(b-a)^2}[f(b)-f(a)-f^\prime(a)(b-a)]
$$
By assumption, $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and twice differentiable on $(a,b)$. Since $h$ is built out of $f$ and polynomials of $x$, it shares the same properties. Thus, Rolle's Theorem applies, and we have a $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
h^\prime(c)=0.
$$
Let us differentiate $h$. We find that $h^\prime(x)=f^\prime(x)-f^\prime(a)-2\alpha(x-a)$. Notice that once again $h^\prime(a)=0$. $f$ is twice differentiable and polynomials are infinitely differentiable on $(a,c)$, so $h$ is also twice differentiable on $(a,c)$. Applying Rolle's Theorem once more, we find a $\xi\in(a,c)$ such that $h^{\prime\prime}(\xi)=0$. $h^{\prime \prime}(x)=f^{\prime\prime}(x)-2\alpha$, so $\alpha=\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)}{2}$. Plugging this back into $(1)$, we get
$$
f(b)=f(a)+f^\prime(a)(b-a)+\frac{f^{\prime\prime}(\xi)}{2!}(b-a)^2
$$
as desired.
I seem to have succeeded, but I'm confused about one thing. I have justified the differentiability of $h^\prime$ on $(a,c)$. I have not, however, showed continuity on $[a,c]$ (as is required for my second application of Rolle's Theorem). From differentiability we have continuity on $(a,c)$ of course, but what about the endpoints? $f$ being continuous does not guarantee that $f^\prime$ is continuous, right?
